# Empty Library when I add JAR file to Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I downloaded the repository from github (https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java), converted it to JAR with the help of online converters (such as this https://convertio.co/), but when I add this JAR to my project, I have an Empty Library error. What's the matter?

[image]

Comment: Show the contents of the library you've configured by double clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the JAR doesn't contain any compiled `.class` files. Since you made the JAR from GitHub, I'm assuming it only contains source `.java` files.

> Dependencies is for the Java classpath, classpath works with .class files (or jars containing .class files). It won't work with sources. If you want to depend on sources, make another Java module and unpack this jar into the source root, then make your main module depend on it.

[Source](https://twitter.com/jetserge/status/1169079293185413121)